# TLS server and normal TCP client in java netty (Client/Server) setup (over local LAN)

Tags: java, ssl, netty, tls1.2

I have a `peer to peer (Client/Server) setup (over local LAN)`, this is using `Netty`,a java networking framework. I use raw `TCP /IP` (as in, no HTTP) for communication and transfers. Now as per requirement we want to shift on `TLS` communication.

> (client using TLS)      <----->  (TLS server)  it works
>
> (simple tcp client) <----->  (TLS server) doesn't work

Please let me know how it will work

Answer (score 0):

Basically all you need to do is to add the `SslHandler` to the pipeline of both and configure it with the correct keys / certs.

Something like:

```
SslContextBuilder builder = ...;
SslContext ctx = builder.build();
pipeline.addLast(ctx.newHandler(channel.alloc()));
```

Comment: Yes, it works if i am configure certificate in both side. Like client certificate on tls client side and server certificate on TLS server side. But the poblem is my existing client is not using TLS so how i will handle those request after adding server certificate on TLS server side.